# Get clean value from field

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

Im trying to render an image with the src being the value of a field. Ofc because this is a field it won't just render the value.

What I need

```
<img class="person--picture" src="{{ content.field_profile_picture_uri }}"/>
```

The field is just a standard text field.

What I've been able to come up with:

```
<img class="person--picture" src="{{ content.field_profile_picture_uri[0]['#context']['value'] }}"/>
```

This works fine but it's not really clean. Anyone know how to do this in Twig?

Comment: Only thing I can imagine is writing a custom function/filter that returns the array part you need to make it "cleaner"

Comment: @DarkBee Too bad, Hoped there would be some kind of twig function to do it.

Comment: Well I was talking about writing a custom twig function so you can use it inside twig ([extending twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html))

Comment: My bad, I meant a predefined function :P Guess I'll do it like this for now.